# Regex String Group Different Status

Tags: javascript, regex

in this case I create a regex for the group in **code,price,name,status** but the last line does not match, I want the last line with status Y if there is no word **[Y]**

```
Harga: 
X25=2.335NAME1 25 [X];
X1=5.720NAME2 5 [Y];
X2=10.720NAME3 10 [Y];
X4=4.200NAME4 4;
```

```js
(?<code>.*)\=(?<price>[0-9]{1,3}\.?[0-9]{1,3})(?<name>.*)\s(?:\[(?<status>X|Y)\])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the first `.*` to a negated character class matching any char except `=`

The name group can be changed to a negated character class matching any char other than `[` and `]`

Using `[0-9]{1,3}\.?[0-9]{1,3}` matches at least 2 digits. If you also want to match a single digits, you can make the `.` and the next 1-3 digits optional

The last part can be made optional including the whitespace char to also match the last line

```
(?<code>[^=\n]*)=(?<price>[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?)(?<name>[^\][]*?)(?:\s*\[(?<status>[XY])\])?;
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<code>[^=\n]*)=` Group *code* match optional chars other than `=`, then match `=`
- `(?<price>` Group *price*

  - `[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?` Match 1-3 digits and optionally `.` and 1-3 digits
- `)` Close gropu
- `(?<name>[^\][]*?)` Group *name*, optionally match any char except `[` and `]` as least as possible
- `(?:` Non capture group to make the whole part optional

  - `\s*\[(?<status>[XY])\]` Optionally match whitespace chars, group *status* matching either `X` or `Y` using a character class between square brackets
- `)?;`  Close the non capture group, and match the `;` at the end

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5BZSde/1)

If the `;` at the end is not mandatory, but it can not occur in between as well, you can exclude matching it as in [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v2ONbt/1).

```js
const regex = /(?<code>[^=\n]*)=(?<price>[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?)(?<name>[^\][]*?)(?:\s*\[(?<status>[XY])\])?;/g;
const str = `Harga: 
X25=2.335NAME1 25 [X];
X1=5.720NAME2 5 [Y];
X2=10.720NAME3 10 [Y];
X4=4.200NAME4 4;`;
let m;

console.log([...str.matchAll(regex)].map(m => m.groups));
```

Comment: thank you so much!! best answer it work!